# How do the Advertisement broadcast popup on the android phone users?

Tags: android, ads, broadcasting

How do i open up an promotional Advertisement(i.e Image,videos,Text Messages ) to all the user's phone having my android application?

All i want to do is 
consider my app to be an tutorial application from an educational institute, now this institute launches an scheme for the students having this application, or they wish to announce for the new upcoming batches to there app users. now they have prepared an image for promotion, and they wish to send this image to all the app user. How can they do this? is there any in android like broadcast or do something to the app users?

Comment: If this ever becomes possible on Android, I will move to a different platform.

Comment: Really . then how does the adv. pops up (about various  games/apps etc.) in various applications?

Comment: In an individual app, yes, driven by the app itself using a library.  But broadcasting popups, yeuch.

Comment: GCM libraries i guess.?? @simon